# pytest, using multiple commands at the same line

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

i have this type of code:

```
@pytest.mark.run(order=2)
@pytest.mark.parametrize('time_ms', range(100, 160, 20))
    def test_wifi_advertising_interval(time_ms):
    test_wifi_screen_edit()
    ....
    ....
```

now, what i want, is to make all the commands (two of them in my case) in one SINGLE line,

like this:

```
@pytestCodeWithSingleLine(pytest.mark.parametrize('time_ms', range(100, 160, 20),pytest.mark.run(order=2)))
```

is it possible somehow?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function to combine decorators pretty easily:

```
def combine(*decorators):
    def combined_decorator(func):
        for deco in decorators:
            func = deco(func)
        return func
    return combined_decorator
```

This is not `pytest` specific, it should work for any combination of decorators that work together when written on separate lines.

While it's not hard to do, that doesn't necessarily mean it's a good idea to do it. I think the two line version of your code is much easier to understand than a combined version on one long line, and so I'd recommend keeping the uncombined version.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and insight!